# Any other way to get a website up without ftp?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-testing

So I have built a website with files that I have coded in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.
I have a purchased a domain and hosting plan at Godaddy.

I'm not sure if FTP will work for me where I am.  I'm not even sure if I can use FTPS or SFTP.

Does GoDaddy offer any other way to upload an entire site?

Comment: You need to read GoDaddy's help.

Comment: Use FTP if available. Unless you know how to SSH. Worried that godaddy might not give you ssh access

Comment: you can use ftp ,file manager in cpanel or git.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is marked as nagative because this seems boared for the users. You should always mention what you did so far.

There are two ways to do this

1) Ask FTP details from Godaddy and upload files here in public_html folder.

2) Login in cpanel, click on File Manager then upload a zip here and extract. You need to move files on the root.

Godaddy is very supportive and helpful, you can take help

Comment: the unzipping is awesome...   the GoDaddy help page on this made it sound like you can only unzip individual files out of the zip file, one at a time --  but it does unzip the all the files and folders... perfect!